# How to find if a specific column is used across views in BigQuery (when the columns are not explicitly written in the view DDL)?

Tags: google-bigquery, information-schema

Let's say I have a table dataset.table1 with columns col1 and col2 in BigQuery.
I create a view dataset.view1 with DDL 'select * from dataset.table1'.

Can I use SQL or a python library, or any other way (without using data lineage or any other additional paid functionality) to find that **col1** and **col2** from dataset.table1 are used in dataset.view1 ?

What about if I create a new view dataset.view2 with DDL 'select * from dataset.view1' ? Is it possible to track down that  **col1** and **col2** from dataset.table1 are used in dataset.view2 ?

I know I can find where specific columns are used in views if the columns are explicity stated (view's DDL is select col1, col2 from dataset.table1) in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
But I wanted to know if I can find where table columns are used in views if not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, data lineage is the right tool for this. I do not know of any other tool doing this task.

A workarount would be to obtail all view queries from  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`. Then parse to find your `dataset.table1` and replace it with `(Select * except(col1) from your dataset.table1)`. Run this as a [dry run](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-dry-run). If it fails, the col1 is needed in this view.

But think of following view:

```
SELECT col2 FROM 
(
Select col1 || "add" as test_column, * 
FROM dataset.table1
)
```

Clearly this view only gives out `col2`, but there are calculations involving `col1`, which are not presented in the final output.
Doing above replacement, the dry query will fail and leading to the wrong conclusion that `col1` is used in the view query.